# Header files without explicitly writing namespace

Tags: c++

In a C++ implementation file, I have the option to write something like:

```
name::space::ClassName::someFunction(int param) {
    // impl
}
```

instead of

```
namespace name {
    namespace space {
        ClassName::someFunction(int param) {
            // impl
        }
    }
}
```

which I find very convenient and more readable. Can this somehow be used in header files, too? Something like this:

```
class name::space::ClassName {
    // declarations
};
```

instead of

```
namespace name {
    namespace space {
        class ClassName {
            // declarations
        };
    }
}
```

If something like this is possible, then under which conditions? I could imagine, that one would need to <strike>forward declare the namespace</strike> forward declare the classes within the namespace like this:

```
namespace name {
    namespace space {
        class ClassName;
    }
}
```

before being able to use this:

```
class name::space::ClassName {
    // declarations
};
```

in a header file.

But somehow I am not able to get this to work **1]**. Is it even possible? What bothers me is, that with nested namespaces I have to indent 2 tabs until I can actually declare my class. I would like to use that space in my header files, but I don't want to omit the tabs since this would be against the "everything in curly brackets needs to be tabbed once"-rule (I don't know if there is an actual name for this. If there is, excuse my ignorance, I don't know any :S

**1]** The problem I faced was not related to the question. The approach actually works, but it has drawbacks (see accepted answer).

Comment: `with nested namespaces I have to indent 2 tabs` you don't really __have__ to, it's about your coding convention. For example, we don't add extra indent for nested namespaces at all where I work.

Comment: a hybrid form of that tabbing rule is to use `namespace name { namespace space {` in one line and indent the rest with just one tab, then end with `} }`

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Which (= not indenting for namespaces) I consider a very sane thing to do.

Comment: The problem is that `name::space::` *refers* to namespace `name` under which another namespace `space` is defined. It *doesn't define* it.

Comment: Yes I know that I could write it inline, but somehow I don't really like it. I am very aware of a uniform convention, which also includes namespaces for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply don't want the namespace braces enveloping your class definition, you can certainly achieve that by defining the namespace somewhere else with just the class declaration inside. That way, you can come up with something like this:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

namespace ClassNamespace { class MyClass; };

class ClassNamespace::MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    void a();
private:

};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

for the header and this:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

ClassNamespace::MyClass::MyClass()
{
}

ClassNamespace::MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

void ClassNamespace::MyClass::a()
{
    cout << "hello";
}
```

for the implementation.

As you can see, the namespace doesn't enclose the class definition, just its declaration.

As a final note, I personally don't know why you'd want to do this or think it looks nicer to read. I'd personally much rather see the namespace encapsulate the class definition *as well as* the function definitions. But maybe I've been the odd one all along...

Comment: It's hard to explain why I like it better. I find it much more readable if I don't want to omit the tabbing when using the encapsulated namespaces. To your answer: So this would actually work? I really like this approach better. Also, if I use one dedicated header where all namespaces for the project are defined, I could better document them (at just one place, instead of on every location where a namespace keyword is used). The drawback on the other hand is obvious; you'd have to maintain another file and include it everywhere...

Comment: It certainly is an interesting idea. That way, you could essentially have one place where you can view all of your classes and the namespaces they belong to. Or perhaps a namespace per file. I really don't think it's standard convention, but it's interesting for sure. I don't think I would mind it.

Comment: Update: Though I liked the idea, I have to admit that storing the namespaces in a seperate file is not practical. If a class is deleted, replaced or renamed, there is no guarantee that the developer remembers to remove the unneeded forward declaration of the class. This will eventually bloat the namespace-file... Anyway, I changed my code like you suggested, with the inline namespace and class forward declaration on top of the class. This is the best compromise for me, so that I can keep my indent-usage and not having to indent twice if I have nested namespaces. Thanks for all answers and help

Answer (score 6):

No, it doesn't work. One problem is that with

```
namespace name {
    namespace space {
        class ClassName {
            // declarations
        }
    }
}
```

you can tell that it is two namespaces and one class.

However, with

```
class name::space::ClassName {
    // declarations
}
```

you cannot tell if `space` is a namespace or a class containing a nested `ClassName`.

What you *can* do is save on your tabbing. It is possible to write

```
namespace name { namespace space {
    class ClassName {
        // declarations
    }
}}
```

Comment: Ah interesting, I wasn't thinking about nested classes. Anyway, if I forward declare the namespaces, then it shouldn't be ambigious, right? Why doesn't it work anyway then? (See OP on the bottom)

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeking does not work.

One explanation is that all C++ `class` and `struct` types are implicitly associated with their own namespace (which has the same name as the class).

So, given

```
class name::space::ClassName
{
// declarations
};
```

the compiler has no way to determine whether `name` and `space` are actually namespaces or classes  (at best, it must conclude that the construct is ambiguous).   So the compiler needs to be explicitly told that `name` is a namespace, that `space` is a namespace within `name`, before being told that `ClassName` is a class within them.

Hence the need for

```
namespace name
{
    namespace space
    {
        class ClassName;
    }
}
```

to forward specify both namespaces and forward declare `ClassName` within them.

Comment: Yes I now understand the problem which comes up. I wasn't thinking about this. However, if I forward declare the namespaces it shouldn't be ambigious, so the compiler could resolve that problem?

Comment: Namespaces are not "forward declared", classes and structs are.   But, to do what you want, it would be necessary to forward declare the classes within the namespaces, as demonstrated by Elephly.

Comment: I fixed the wrong terminology in the OP, thanks for making me aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. The only way to **define** a namespace is using the `namespace` keyword in combination with curly braces.

> **7.3.1 Namespace definition [namespace.def]**
>
> 1 The grammar for a namespace-definition is
>
> ```
>   namespace-name:
>       original-namespace-name
>       namespace-alias
>   original-namespace-name:
>       identifier
>   namespace-definition:
>       named-namespace-definition
>       unnamed-namespace-definition
>   named-namespace-definition:
>       original-namespace-definition
>       extension-namespace-definition
>   original-namespace-definition:
>       inlineopt namespace identifier { namespace-body }
>   extension-namespace-definition:
>       inlineopt namespace original-namespace-name { namespace-body }
>   unnamed-namespace-definition:
>       inlineopt namespace { namespace-body }
>   namespace-body:
>       declaration-seqopt
> ```

You can define namespace's members outside the namespace, although it must have been **declared** inside the `namespace` (emphasis mine):

> **7.3.1.2 Namespace member definitions [namespace.memdef]**
>
> 2 Members of a named namespace can also be *defined outside* that namespace by explicit qualification (3.4.3.2)
>   of the name being defined, provided that the entity being defined was already **declared in the namespace**
>   and the definition appears after the point of declaration in a namespace that encloses the declaration’s
>   namespace.

When you write

```
namespace name {
    namespace space {
        class ClassName;
    }
}
```

you are not declaring a `class ClassName` into the `namespace space`, you are just providing a *forward declaration*.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about specifying the namespace in a class definition.

Comment: @interjay Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, much better. However, the OP says he tried to declare the class in the namespace before defining it and it didn't work.

Comment: @interjay I think the problem is that he has not declared the class into the namespace, but he has just forward declared it.

Comment: I had an other problem unrelated to the question, it actually works now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Stricktly speaking, there is no such fing as "forward"-declaration. It's either a declaration, or a definition. So `class MyClass;` is a class-declaration, and that is sufficient.